# How do i encrypt more than one object using jsobwebtoken?

Tags: node.js, express, json-web-token

Currently I want to store more than one object using jsonwebtoken

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {

      var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
       expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE
     });
});
```

How do I store additional data like

```
 var isMerchant = true
 var token = jwt.sign(user, isMerchant, config.secret, {
       expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE
  });
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the object that is encoded, so you will need to append your property to the `user` object if you want to encode it.

```js
// add the property here
user.isMerchant = true;

var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
  expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE
});
```

It looks like you are using Sequelize, so you probably also want to query using the `raw: true` parameter or call `user.toJSON()` before encoding it so you are just saving the values and not the `Model`, or some version of it.